# How to use Dokka to generate Docs like Kotlinlang.org

Tags: android, kotlin, documentation-generation, kdoc, kotlin-dokka

AFAIK [Kotlin's Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html) was made using Dokka. But the Examples stated in [Dokka's Readme](https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka) is only generating ultra basic webpages/markdown files with no elegance whatsoever.

It just looks like this

[image]

Here's another one by [Atrium](https://github.com/robstoll/atrium), docs [link](https://docs.atriumlib.org/0.8.0/doc/index.html).

[image]

I'm wondering if I'm doing anything wrong.

I've also looked at the issues page and been browsing through other open source github projects that has used **Dokka** and the result is always the same.

Now a good example of how a tool that generates beautiful documentation would be [Jazzy](https://github.com/realm/jazzy) by [Realm](https://realm.io) for Swift/Obj-C. Using it can be as easy as running one command on the terminal.

Here's an example documentation created using Jazzy

[image]

Further research with suggests that I may have to use third party tools like [Gitbook](https://www.gitbook.com) or [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com) to generate the kind of documentation I'm looking, is that really the only way?

Comment: are you asking how to use dokka, or are you asking for tool recommendations?

Comment: I'm asking about Dokka, let me update the question

Comment: Did you find out how to make it more elegant, @ZonilyJame??

Comment: Sadly no @Pabloku, the only way to beautify it, in my knowledge, is to use third party tools.

Comment: And could you recomend any third party tool? I am trying https://orchid.netlify.com/

Comment: Right now I'm using Dokka to generate markdown files that I could use with mkdocs

Answer (score 2):

Kotlinlang uses some custom styles for one of the dokka's output formats. Development on some better looking docs is underway

Comment: Avoid one liner comment as answer, Provide solution to question, else simply comment

Comment: I would have commented but I don't not have enough reputation to do it